# Map groups to roles in Keycloak when using OIDC - Roles are not appending based on new Groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak

I mapped AD groups to roles using `Mappers`. When I login with test user(with ADGroup1, ADGroup2),
In the Keycloak logged-in user's mapper roles (role1, role2) are assigned correctly.

When I remove a user from an AD group (-ADGroup2) in Azure. It was deleting role (-role2) in Keycloak after logging in again.

I tried to add the AD group (ADGroup2) back again. It was not an appending role again. Seeing only role1.

Mapper is configured as below:

`ADGroup1` ==> `test_client.role1`

`ADGroup2` ==> `test_client.role2`

If I delete both AD groups, user roles are also deleted in Keycloak. only appending is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for posting your query. This seems like a user data sync delay. Could you please try to have "**Sync Mode Override**" to "**force**". This would update user data at each user login. Ref: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/server_admin/topics/identity-broker/mappers.adoc

Thanks